# Python: Accessing the proper values in an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I want to calculate the following equation:

```
calc = value_a(2D) - (value_b(0D) + value_b(1D))/10000

value_a(2D) corresponds to type **a**, year **2D** and value **1.1275**
value_b(0D) corresponds to type **b**, year **0D** and value **0**
value_b(1D) corresponds to type **b**, year **1D** and value **0.125**
```

and the result should be

`1.1274875`

but somwhow I am not sure how to access the proper data within my loop? I would like to keep my structure of the code.

The code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('C:/Book1.csv').fillna('')
pd_date = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date'].values)
data['date'] = pd_date
index_data = data.set_index('date')

for current_date in index_data.index.unique():
    for index, row in index_data.iterrows():
        if index == current_date:
            for index2, row2 in index_data.iterrows(): 
                if index2 == current_date:    
                    if row['type'] in {'a', 'b'} and row2['type'] in {'a', 'b'}:
                        if row['year'] in {'0D','1D','2D'}:
                            print(row['value'])
```

The data looks like the following:

> ```
> date          type    year    value
> 2015-02-09    a       2D      1.1275
> 2015-02-09    b       10M     58.125
> 2015-02-09    b       11M     68.375
> 2015-02-09    b       1M      3.345
> 2015-02-09    b       1W      0.89
> 2015-02-09    b       1Y      79.375
> 2015-02-09    b       2M      7.535
> 2015-02-09    b       2W      1.8
> 2015-02-09    b       3M      11.61
> 2015-02-09    b       3W      2.48
> 2015-02-09    b       4M      16.2
> 2015-02-09    b       5M      21.65
> 2015-02-09    b       6M      27.1
> 2015-02-09    b       7M      33.625
> 2015-02-09    b       8M      41.375
> 2015-02-09    b       9M      49.5
> 2015-02-09    b       0D      0
> 2015-02-09    b       1D      0.125
> ```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Especially what is value_a and value_b and where they come from.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thanks a lot for your answer. I updated the description.

Comment: How is the column `'type'` relating to things here? It seems completely superfluous, or it's relationship to your equation isn't really obvious from the example you have given. EDIT: In other words, it looks like you are just selecting the values corresponding to the `'year'`, for `'2D'` etc..

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, type is important because I have more types than a and b. I wanted to keep the data extraction simpler. I updated the description above.

Comment: Right. It's still not obvious. What would `value_b(2D)` look like? Your example doesn't allow me to infer the logic relating things. What other values can your columns have? More exactly, what other combination of values, and what exactly is the purpose of *type*? Notice, I can easily get your numbers just by using the `'value'` that corresponds to the `'year'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you really could use a multi-index here:

```
In [4]: df.reset_index(inplace=True)

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   type year        date    value
0     a   2D  2015-02-09   1.1275
1     b  10M  2015-02-09  58.1250
2     b  11M  2015-02-09  68.3750
3     b   1M  2015-02-09   3.3450
4     b   1W  2015-02-09   0.8900
5     b   1Y  2015-02-09  79.3750
6     b   2M  2015-02-09   7.5350
7     b   2W  2015-02-09   1.8000
8     b   3M  2015-02-09  11.6100
9     b   3W  2015-02-09   2.4800
10    b   4M  2015-02-09  16.2000
11    b   5M  2015-02-09  21.6500
12    b   6M  2015-02-09  27.1000
13    b   7M  2015-02-09  33.6250
14    b   8M  2015-02-09  41.3750
15    b   9M  2015-02-09  49.5000
16    b   0D  2015-02-09   0.0000
17    b   1D  2015-02-09   0.1250

In [6]: df.set_index(['type','year'], inplace=True)


In [7]: df
Out[7]:
                 date    value
type year
a    2D    2015-02-09   1.1275
b    10M   2015-02-09  58.1250
     11M   2015-02-09  68.3750
     1M    2015-02-09   3.3450
     1W    2015-02-09   0.8900
     1Y    2015-02-09  79.3750
     2M    2015-02-09   7.5350
     2W    2015-02-09   1.8000
     3M    2015-02-09  11.6100
     3W    2015-02-09   2.4800
     4M    2015-02-09  16.2000
     5M    2015-02-09  21.6500
     6M    2015-02-09  27.1000
     7M    2015-02-09  33.6250
     8M    2015-02-09  41.3750
     9M    2015-02-09  49.5000
     0D    2015-02-09   0.0000
     1D    2015-02-09   0.1250
```

Then simply:

```
In [8]: df.loc['a','2D'].value  - (df.loc['b', '0D'].value + df.loc['b','1D'].value)/10000
Out[8]: 1.1274875
```

Note, suppose I have multiple years (this I made by simply concatenating the df to itself):

```
In [24]: df2
Out[24]:
   type year        date    value
0     a   2D  2015-02-09   1.1275
1     b  10M  2015-02-09  58.1250
2     b  11M  2015-02-09  68.3750
3     b   1M  2015-02-09   3.3450
4     b   1W  2015-02-09   0.8900
5     b   1Y  2015-02-09  79.3750
6     b   2M  2015-02-09   7.5350
7     b   2W  2015-02-09   1.8000
8     b   3M  2015-02-09  11.6100
9     b   3W  2015-02-09   2.4800
10    b   4M  2015-02-09  16.2000
11    b   5M  2015-02-09  21.6500
12    b   6M  2015-02-09  27.1000
13    b   7M  2015-02-09  33.6250
14    b   8M  2015-02-09  41.3750
15    b   9M  2015-02-09  49.5000
16    b   0D  2015-02-09   0.0000
17    b   1D  2015-02-09   0.1250
18    a   2D  2015-02-10   1.1275
19    b  10M  2015-02-10  58.1250
20    b  11M  2015-02-10  68.3750
21    b   1M  2015-02-10   3.3450
22    b   1W  2015-02-10   0.8900
23    b   1Y  2015-02-10  79.3750
24    b   2M  2015-02-10   7.5350
25    b   2W  2015-02-10   1.8000
26    b   3M  2015-02-10  11.6100
27    b   3W  2015-02-10   2.4800
28    b   4M  2015-02-10  16.2000
29    b   5M  2015-02-10  21.6500
30    b   6M  2015-02-10  27.1000
31    b   7M  2015-02-10  33.6250
32    b   8M  2015-02-10  41.3750
33    b   9M  2015-02-10  49.5000
34    b   0D  2015-02-10   0.0000
35    b   1D  2015-02-10   0.1250

In [25]: df.iloc[-2,-1] = 100000 # this corresponds to (b, 0D) and used to be 0
```

As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ noted, you can group by the `'date'` column:

```
In [26]: df2.groupby('date').apply(
     ...:     lambda df:
     ...:         df.loc['a','2D'].value
     ...:         - (df.loc['b', '0D'].value + df.loc['b','1D'].value)
     ...:         / 10000
     ...: )
Out[27]:
date
2015-02-09    1.127487
2015-02-10   -8.872513
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ah, this is the answer OP needs.