# Nested Loop Python calculation of values in a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, nested-loops

I would like to calculate the following function in a **nested loop and keep it that way**:

```
Calc_Value = value_a(2D) - (values_b(0D) + values_b(1D))/10000
```

which results in the value:

```
1.1274875
```

which is defined as:

```
value_a(2D) corresponds to type **a**, year **2D** and value **1.1275**
value_b(0D) corresponds to type **b**, year **0D** and value **0**
value_b(1D) corresponds to type **b**, year **1D** and value **0.125**
```

somehow I am not sure how to define the function below to use for value b the proper two values as shown above???

There is a way how to do it in directly with pandas ([Pandas Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551985/python-accessing-the-proper-values-in-an-array?noredirect=1#comment86114602_49551985)) but would like to use my nested way.

***UPDATE:***

I cahnged my function and receive thr proper value but still have the problem that I calculate the value several time instead of one time. I get for every value b the value a until the proper value is calculated which is the last one. I only want to keep the last value.

> ```
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1275
> 1.1274875 --> **Only this value should be shown**
> ```

The code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

def CalcValue(year, a, b):  
    normalization = 0.0
    value_0D = 0.0
    value_1D = 0.0
    Calc = 0.0
    normalization = 10000.0
    if year == "0D":    
        value_0D = b
    elif year == "1D":
        value_1D = b
    Calc = a-(value_0D+value_1D)/normalization            
    return Calc


data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/mcm/Desktop/Book1.csv').fillna('')

pd_date = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date'].values)
data['date'] = pd_date
index_data = data.set_index('date')

for current_date in index_data.index.unique():    
    print('calculating date: ' + str(current_date))

    for index, row in index_data.iterrows():
        if index == current_date:
            for index2, row2 in index_data.iterrows(): 
                if index2 == current_date:
                    if row['type'] in {'a', 'b'} and row2['type'] in {'a', 'b'}:
                        if row['type'] != row2['type'] and row['type'] != 'a' and row2['type'] != 'b':  
                            test = CalcValue(row['year'], row2['value'],row['value'])
                            print(test)
```

The data looks like the following:

```
date    type    year    value
2015-02-09  a   2D  1.1275
2015-02-09  b   10M 58.125
2015-02-09  b   11M 68.375
2015-02-09  b   1M  3.345
2015-02-09  b   1W  0.89
2015-02-09  b   1Y  79.375
2015-02-09  b   2M  7.535
2015-02-09  b   2W  1.8
2015-02-09  b   3M  11.61
2015-02-09  b   3W  2.48
2015-02-09  b   4M  16.2
2015-02-09  b   5M  21.65
2015-02-09  b   6M  27.1
2015-02-09  b   7M  33.625
2015-02-09  b   8M  41.375
2015-02-09  b   9M  49.5
2015-02-09  b   0D  0
2015-02-09  b   1D  0.125
2015-02-09  c   2Y  -28.5
2015-02-09  c   3Y  -28.75
2015-02-09  c   4Y  -28
2015-02-09  c   5Y  -27.5
2015-02-09  c   6Y  -27
2015-02-09  c   7Y  -26.75
2015-02-09  c   8Y  -26.25
2015-02-09  c   9Y  -25.5
2015-02-09  c   10Y -25
2015-02-10  a   2D  1.1297
2015-02-10  b   10M 60.5
2015-02-10  b   11M 70.375
2015-02-10  b   1M  3.32
2015-02-10  b   1W  0.84
2015-02-10  b   1Y  81.625
2015-02-10  b   2M  7.54
2015-02-10  b   2W  1.74
2015-02-10  b   3M  11.745
2015-02-10  b   3W  2.45
2015-02-10  b   4M  16.4
2015-02-10  b   5M  22.05
2015-02-10  b   6M  28.1
2015-02-10  b   7M  35.375
2015-02-10  b   8M  42.625
2015-02-10  b   9M  51
2015-02-10  b   0D  0.105
2015-02-10  b   1D  0.11
2015-02-10  c   2Y  -29.5
2015-02-10  c   3Y  -29.75
2015-02-10  c   4Y  -29.5
2015-02-10  c   5Y  -29
2015-02-10  c   6Y  -28.5
2015-02-10  c   7Y  -28
2015-02-10  c   8Y  -27.5
2015-02-10  c   9Y  -26.75
2015-02-10  c   10Y -26.25
```

Comment: Your code does not run [syntax error on `values_b(0D)`]. Please provide a [mcve]. You have provided a description, but it's more useful to provide your existing, *error-free* solution.

Comment: Please add `pandas` tag on next edit.

Comment: @jpp, thanks a lot for the answer. I included a running code but without the lines which I need. I would like to solve it without pandas functions etc but just with indexing and nested loops.

Comment: @handle, thanks a lot for the answer. I added pandas in it but I would like to solve it without pandas functions etc but just with indexing and nested loops

Comment: @jpp, I again updated my code but still struggeling on it.

Comment: @handle, I again updated my code but still struggeling on it.

Comment: You ignored jpp's advice and are now nagging - really?

Comment: @handle, which advice? The code is updated and runs with exapmples how the value should look like?

Comment: The advice to show some effort and reduce your code to something easier to help with: [mcve] (doing this also likely gets you thinking and figuring it out yourself). You could also add more debug output or use actual debugging to find out where your code does not do what you expect it to.

Comment: @handle, as I Said it is already the minimum complete example. I changed things as you can see in the updated section. For me it is still not clear how much more minimum it should be? Because more minimum means no code! In addition, the code is running and shows results.

Answer (score 0):

This would be minimal:

```
for i in range(20):
    print(i)
#print(i)
```

This includes a condition:

```
for i in range(20):
    if True:
        test = i
        print(test)
#print(test)
```

Your problem is just to **get the last computed value from a loop** - you already achieved this, but you are printing every computed value *inside* the loop, i.e. on every iteration where the conditions are met. The quick solution is to just print it *after* the loop (swap the comments on print() above).

You would generally stop the loop once you found what your are looking for. Otherwise, you'd use another variable to store the result:

```
keepitthatway = None
for i in range(42):
    if i==7:
        keepitthatway = i
        # keep on iterating if necessary or
        #break
print(i)
print(keepitthatway)
```

There are lots of Python programming tutorials out there, e.g. https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop. Have a look ;-)

---

Regarding [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this would have worked too. While not exactly minimal, it resembles your code structure:

```
for current_date in range(2):
    print('calculating something...')
    for index, row in enumerate(range(20)):
        if index == current_date:
            for index2, row2 in enumerate(range(20)):
                if True:
                    if True:
                        if True:
                            test = index
                            print(test)
    #print(test)
```

Just limiting your dataset would have been an improvement already:

```
import pandas as pd

# pretend to be the csv file
import io
csv = io.StringIO("""date\ttype\tyear\tvalue
2015-02-09\ta\t2D\t1.1275
2015-02-09\tb\t10M\t58.125
2015-02-09\tc\t2Y\t-28.5
2015-02-10\ta\t2D\t1.1297
2015-02-10\tb\t10M\t60.5
2015-02-10\tc\t2Y\t-29.5
2015-02-10\tc\t10Y\t-26.25
""")

def CalcValue(year, a, b):
    normalization = 0.0
    value_0D = 0.0
    value_1D = 0.0
    Calc = 0.0
    normalization = 10000.0
    if year == "0D":
        value_0D = b
    elif year == "1D":
        value_1D = b
    Calc = a-(value_0D+value_1D)/normalization
    return Calc

data = pd.read_csv(csv, sep="\t").fillna('')

#print(data)
#import sys;sys.exit()

pd_date = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date'].values)
data['date'] = pd_date
index_data = data.set_index('date')

for current_date in index_data.index.unique():
    print('calculating date: ' + str(current_date))

    for index, row in index_data.iterrows():
        if index == current_date:
            for index2, row2 in index_data.iterrows():
                if index2 == current_date:
                    if row['type'] in {'a', 'b'} and row2['type'] in {'a', 'b'}:
                        if row['type'] != row2['type'] and row['type'] != 'a' and row2['type'] != 'b':
                            test = CalcValue(row['year'], row2['value'],row['value'])
    print(test)
```

Prints

```
calculating date: 2015-02-09 00:00:00
1.1275
calculating date: 2015-02-10 00:00:00
1.1297
```

(of course these values are different from the one in your question, because the dataset is modified)